# Меню на jQuery

Tags: меню, jquery

Здравствуйте, поставил код меню с вложенными подпунктами, все работает отлично, вот только при входе на сайт первый пункт вложенного меню всегда открыт автоматически, как сделать, чтоб все пункты меню были закрыты до тех пор, пока по нему не кликнешь?

Код настройки скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
ddaccordion.init({
    headerclass: "headerbar",
    //Shared CSS class name of headers group
    contentclass: "submenu",
    //Shared CSS class name of contents group
    revealtype: "mouseover",
    //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the header? Valid value: "click", "clickgo", or "mouseover"
    mouseoverdelay: 200,
    //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds before header expands onMouseover
    collapseprev: true,
    //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false
    defaultexpanded: [0],
    //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc] [] denotes no content
    onemustopen: true,
    //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
    animatedefault: false,
    //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
    persiststate: true,
    //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
    toggleclass: ["", "selected"],
    //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
    togglehtml: ["", "", ""],
    //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
    animatespeed: "normal",
    //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
    oninit: function (headers, expandedindices) { //custom code to run when headers have initalized
        //do nothing
    },
    onopenclose: function (header, index, state, isuseractivated) { //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
        //do nothing
    }
})   
</script>
```

Сам скрипт: (довольно большой, поэтому выкладываю ссылку на него) [ddaccordion.js](http://best-serials.ru/ddaccordion.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего куки запомнили состояние меню. Попробуйте установить `persiststate = false`.

Со скриптом все нормально. В настройках установите 
`defaultexpanded: [], onemustopen: false`.

Comment: Пробовал, изначально эта функция была отключена, но все равно при первом запуске, когда он уже отображал первый пункт раскрытым. Как я понимаю, такова особенность самого кода, а не какая-то ошибка в настройках, потому что в демо режиме он отображался так же с раскрытым первым пунктом меню.

Спасибо :) Вроде как помогло :)